iTunes iPhone Synchronization Log on Windows?
Does iTunes for Windows store any kind of log of files and items synchronized in its last sesssion?
Every day that I sync my iPhone to iTunes for Windows it shows that it is copying over 15 photos.  It takes a very long time and I have no idea what it is copying.  Even if I have taken no new photos, when I come back to sync again, it starts copying some mystery 15 photos.  I suspect they are video files given how long it takes to copy and sync and that something is bugged causing them to sync again and again and again. I’d like to figure out what they are and clean/remove them.
I’m syncing an iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 17.4.1 on Windows 11 running iTunes latest version.
